# Is it too late to bring up starting equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, group-dynamics

Our game has already begun, and we are in fact already several levels in. However, I have noticed that a few things have been skipped/misinterpreted in terms of starting equipment.

I understand that for some, things such as gold might be skipped over by preference of the DM, but other things such as starting equipment might be another matter.

I do know that in our particular group, while the DM is quite experienced (~30 years of pure DMing), he has said that he is still fairly new to the D&D 5e system (our current game).

If I wanted to discuss this with the group, how might I go about it?

Comment: Have you run into any actual problems because of this? A few levels in, it seems unlikely that you haven't been able to upgrade or buy retroactively any equipment you should've started with. If you have issues because of missing gear, it's probably best to use that as a starting point. But if there's no actual problems it might be better to just keep it in mind for the next game.

Comment: Do you mean you have problems because you have the whole time had equipment the GM now has decided to make rare and valuable for plot reasons, but which he or she seems unaware you already have?

Comment: In answer to your last paragraph: your first paragraph is a good way.